# Pandas DataFrame: programmatic rows split of a dataframe on multiple columns conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

### Context

I'm working on a DataFrame `df` with lots of columns filled with numerical values

```
df
lorem ipsum  |  dolor sic  |  ...  |  (hundreds of cols)
---------------------------------------------------------
0.5          |     -6.2    |  ...  | 79.8
-26.1        |     6200.0  |  ...  | -65.2
150.0        |     3.14    |  ...  | 1.008
```

By another mean, I have a `list_cols` of columns:

```
list_cols = ['lorem ipsum', 'dolor sic', ... ]  # arbitrary length, of course len(list_cols ) <= len(df.columns), and contains valid columns of my df
```

I want to obtain 2 dataframes :

- 1 that contains all rows where `value < 0` for at least one of `list_cols` (corresponds to a `OR` ). let's call it `negative_values_matches`
- 1 that corresponds to the remaining of dataframe, lets call it `positive_values_matches`

---

### Expected result example

for `list_cols = ['lorem ipsum', 'dolor sic']`, I shall obtain dataframes were at least 1 value in list_cols is strictly negative:

```
negative_values_matches
lorem ipsum  |  dolor sic  |  ...  |  (hundreds of cols)
---------------------------------------------------------
0.5          |     -6.2    |  ...  | 79.8
-26.1        |     6200.0  |  ...  | -65.2


positive_values_matches
lorem ipsum  |  dolor sic  |  ...  |  (hundreds of cols)
---------------------------------------------------------
150.0        |     3.14    |  ...  | 1.008
```

---

I don't want to write myslef this kind of code:

```
negative_values_matches = df[ (criterion1 | criterion2 | ... | criterionn)]
positive_values_matches = df[~(criterion1 | criterion2 | ... | criterionn)]
```

(where `criterionk` is a boolean evaluation for column `k` such as for instance: `(df[col_k]>=0)`, parenthesis intended here since its the Pandas syntax)

The idea is to have a **programmatic** approach.
I'm mainly looking for an array of booleans, so I can then use *Boolean indexing* (see [Pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)).

As far as I can tell, these posts are not *exactly* what I am talking about:

- [Filtering DataFrame on multiple conditions in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48292493/filtering-dataframe-on-multiple-conditions-in-pandas)
- [Drop rows on multiple conditions in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52456874/drop-rows-on-multiple-conditions-in-pandas-dataframe)
- [Pandas: np.where with multiple conditions on dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27717111/pandas-np-where-with-multiple-conditions-on-dataframes)
- [Pandas DataFrame : How to select rows on multiple conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45590769/pandas-dataframe-how-to-select-rows-on-multiple-conditions) This one is a little bit closer to what I am looking for. However, it relies on generating a string that might not work with "exotic" column names (spaces) (or at least I don't know how to do it)

I can't figure out how to chain the booleans evaluations on my DataFrame altogether with `OR`operator anbd obtain the correct rows splitting.

What can I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several attempts, I managed to achieve my goal.

Here is the code:

```
import Pandas
import numpy
# assume dataframe exists
df = ...
# initiliaze an array of False, matching df number of rows
resulting_bools = numpy.zeros((1, len(df.index)), dtype=bool)

for col in list_cols:
    # obtain array of booleans for given column and boolean condition for [row, column] value
    criterion = df[col].map(lambda x: x < 0) # same condition for each column, different conditions would have been more difficult (for me)

     # perform cumulative boolean evaluation accross columns
    resulting_bools |= criterion

# use the array of booleans to build the required df
negative_values_matches = df[ resulting_bools].copy() # use .copy() to avoid further possible warnings from Pandas depending on what you do with your data frame
positive_values_matches = df[~resulting_bools].copy()
```

This way, I successfully obtained 2 dataframes:

- 1 with all rows that have a value < 0 for at least 1 of the column in `list_cols`
- 1 with all other rows (value >= 0 for each col in `list_col`)

(The array initialization on False depends on the boolean evaluations choices)

---

NB: The approach could be combined with [multiple conditions on dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49513661/multiple-conditions-on-dataframes). To be confirmed.